# App icon is not rounded on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-simulator

I have strange problem with an app icon. When I run app on iphone simulator the icon is rounded, but on iPhone the app icon shape is square.
How to fix that ?

Comment: Screenshots of what ? iPhone ? iPhone simulator .plist file ?

Comment: screenshots of the simulator and the iphone (using organizer works best)

Comment: iPhone screenshot - http://img197.imageshack.us/i/iphonen.png/

Simulator screenshot - http://img52.imageshack.us/i/simulatorxn.png/

Answer (score 2):

Check that you haven't got `UIPrerenderedIcon` set in your plist file. This let's you turn the rounded corners/shine off if you want to do it yourself.

There's a little info on this option here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html
(Search for `UIPrerenderedIcon`)

Comment: I have no such a key in plist

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem but with a jailbroken phone. In my case this happens because I ssh (use ssh to transfer file) the directory "myAppName".app straight into the device's file system (/Applications).

Gloss effect is applied and corners get automatically rounded when the app is installed via MobileInstallation - in other words iTunes, Xcode or App Store.

Sadly i have not found a free of charge solution yet. So if this is a critical problem i suggest you should buy the IOS developer licence.